# Bulk Import content from CSV file in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I have a website that needs to periodically import 600-800 records from a CSV file.

As part of the import, the existing records are removed / deleted, then replaced by the newly imported data.

At present I am removing the existing items like this:

```
var itemsToRemove = _contentManager.Query(VersionOptions.Published, "Store").List();

foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
{
   _contentManager.Remove(item);
}
```

Then importing my new records like so:

```
var item = _contentManager.New("Store");

item.As<TitlePart>().Title = title;
item.As<StorePart>().Address1 = address1;

_contentManager.Create(item);
```

It works, but the process is taking so long that it is timing out.

Can anyone suggest a better or more efficient way of doing this? Or tell me how I could extend the timeout duration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Import performance isn't that great in orchard right now. So this is a known issue. If you can use the standard import/export interface you could try to increase the batchsize. Of course you'd need to convert the csv to xml for this.
We face a similar problem right now and tend towards not importing the content at all and instead use a rest endpoint to retrieve it on demand.

Comment: First, I think you don't need the .List() to iterate through the list you get from the query, second maybe you could try with the _contentManager.Destroy() method for permanent erase.
Beside those you could handle the process through an asynchronous method (Web API Controller), so no timing out will occur.
I think you couldn't do the content item creation to be faster, but it shouldn't time out IMO.
Have you thought about it that maybe you shouldn't need to delete those existing content items? Maybe an update on them will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I wanted to avoid having to write a separate service to handle it, but it's certainly worth considering. And unfortunately I don't have a unique identifier, so switching to an update could be a bit awkward. I'll check Destroy() out though - cheers.